# Read firebase push notification to app local nosql DB

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Anyone suggest me How to Store the push notifications to the App local nosql DB in xamarin forms.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain the question with more details.

Comment: I am developing a xamarin forms application. In which I am receiving push notifications from the Google firebase. Now I need to read the content of the notifications and store it in app local DB. Also I need to list all notification received by the user in a screen.

Comment: what do you mean by nosql db?